# Quantum Logic and Quantum Field Theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, foundations

Quantum Logic is a very interesting and powerful answer to the problem of Quantum Mechanics foundations. Nevertheless this approach is usually developed in a non-relativistic framework. Is it still valid in a relativistic one? Can one talk about Yes/No experiments, elementary propositions lattice and so on also in the context of Quantum Field Theory?

Answer (score -1):

I did not learn the quantum theory on a relativistic view. It's true that it's a hard topic to understand thats why it may look so relative, but as I was told it isn't, we just don't have all the informations we need about it. **You can work on yes/no experiments**. In some books writes that light behaves like a wave AND like a particle, but in fact **wave is a feature of the particle**, it depends how it is manifested but it can't be 2 things at once. So only the theories of scientists about quantum mechanics are relative, some vary a lot.

Comment: I do not believe this actually answers the question that was asked.

Comment: I understood the question totally wrong. I didn't read it carefully. Sorry, my mistake !